# How to display MousePosition outside map container?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

I am a new to OpenLayers. 
By Default the MousePosition displays the coordinates within the map.

I need to display the coordinates outside the map is a specific place. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

The [OpenLayers.Control documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control-js.html) says:

> Controls by default are added to the map they are contained within
>   however it is possible to add a control to an external div by passing
>   the div in the options parameter.

So you just need to pass the div to the control while initialising it, somewhat like this:

```
var mp=new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({'div':pos});
map.addControl(mp);
```

Here is a [working JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devdatta/285Z6/2/) which demonstrates this.